# Multiple Tensorflow Instances on GPU

Tags: tensorflow

I am interested on how to execute multiple tensorflow instances on a single GPU. I know for each instance the memory needs to be a fraction of the complete GPU memory. But, I am unsure how to span multiple tensorflow on a single GPU. Any suggestions ?

Comment: The runtime should take care of this for you. Are you trying to train multiple models at the same time? That is wrong. Are you running inference for multiple sets at the same time on the same device? Those should be queued.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to run 2 or more instances of inference in single GPU.